# Не могу добавить данные, пришедшие из базы данных, в массив(Node js, sequelize, Postgresql)

Tags: javascript, node.js

*Имеется массив видов спорта.*

```
sports = [
  "Футбол",
  "Теннис",
  "Хоккей",
  "Баскетбол",
  "Волейбол",
]
```

**По нему идет перебор, который ищет данные с этим видом спорта в* базе данных.*

```
let matches = []
sports.forEach(async(item, i, arr) => {
  matches.push(await table.findAll({where:{"sport": item},limit,page}))
})
```

*Однако при отправке ответа* `response.send(matches)` *отправляется пустой массив*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что у вас в forEach асинхронная функция, если вы хотите дождаться выполнения всех запросов, то используйте обычный цикл

```
for (let i = 0; i < sports.length; i++) {
  matches.push(await table.findAll({
    where: {
      "sport": sports[i]
    },
    limit,
    page
  }))
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало.